# My attempt at K&R Exercise 1-13 is making bars way too long

Tags: c

My code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

main() {
  int nwords[10];
  int c;
  int i;
  int firstLetter;

  c=0;
  i=0;
  firstLetter=0;

  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (isalpha(c)) {
      firstLetter = 1;
      i++;
    }
    if (firstLetter != 0) {
      nwords[i]++;
      i=0;
    }
  }

  for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
    printf("%d, ");
    while (nwords[i] > 0) {
      printf("=");
      -- nwords[i];
    }
    if (nwords[i] == 0) {
      printf("/n");
    }
  }
}
```

I expect the ouptut to be a horizontal histogram that shows the frequency of word lengths in the input file like so:

```
10 ===
9 ==
8
7 ==== 
6 = 
5 ======
4 ===
3 =
2 = 
1 =
```

But instead, my program spams space bars  until I have to kill it.

What did I do wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Try compiling it with all warnings enabled. It should warn about usage of uninitialized variables.

Comment: `int nwords[10];` does not initialized. Change it to `int nwords[10] = {0};`

Comment: `printf("%d, ");` : The value to be displayed is required as an argument. And `printf("/n");` --> `printf("\n");`

Comment: `if (firstLetter != 0) {` --> `else if (firstLetter != 0) {`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY 'i' isn't supposed to update though; 'i' represents the word length, and 'nwords[i]' represents the amount of words with that word length. 'while (nwords[i] > 0)' means while there is a non-zero amount of words with word length 'i'. So only 'nwords[i]' is supposed to update inside the loop body, not 'i'.

Comment: @ZhengboXiang Yes, I was wrong. So I deleted that comment already.(quite before).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after `for (i=0; i<10; i++)` change `printf("%d, ")` with `printf("%d", variable)` Give the variable which value is to be replaced with `%d`.
And replace `printf("/n");` with `printf("\n");`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to surjit's answer, you need to make the following change:

int nwords[10] = {0};